# Auto append table row (at bottom) showing total computation

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a data to display in html table. The data comes from the 3rd party server(php) using ajax request. The data are well displayed using this code:
HTML:

```
 <table id="tbl-product">
   <tr>
         <th>product</th>
         <th>date</th>
         <th>quantity</th>
         <th>cost</th>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

And the ajax call where in the data will display on success ( `success: function(data, status, jqXHR){` ):

```
data.forEach(function(row) {
                    var productname = row.uproducts_product;
                    var productico = productname.replace(/\s+/g, "-") + '.png';
                    
                    var productcost = row.uproducts_total_investment;
                    
                    var str = '<tr>'; 
                    str += '<td>' + '<img class="product_icon" src="images/products/icon-'+ productico +'">' + '<div class="productname">'+ row.uproducts_product + '</div></td>';
                    str += '<td><div class="textinfo ">' + row.date + '<br/><span class="date">' +  row.uproducts_date + '</span></div> </td>';
                    str += '<td><span class="textinfo">' + row.uproducts_quantity + '</span></td>';
                    str += '<td><span class="textinfo">' + productcost + '</td>';
                    str += '</tr>';
                    
                    $('#tbl-product').append(str);
                   
                });
```

So, the items are displayed like this

**product** |      **date**      | **quantity** |   **cost**

A       |       12-01-2015   |      2      |  2,100

B      |   01-04-2016     |    4     |   5,300

But below the product items, I want to add a row which auto compute the total quantity as well as the total cost. Example:

**product** |      **date**      | **quantity** |   **cost**

A       |       12-01-2015   |      2      |  2,100.00

B      |   01-04-2016     |    4     |   5,300.00

Total     |   6(quantity)    | 7,400.00(cost)

Updated1 **Alternatives**: I created an alternative here, I added a variable for the computed total in the array where the server respond it as json data.
So the data now look like this:

```
[{
"id":"11",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes A",
"quantity":"1",
"open":"2015-01-04",
"investment":"3000"
},

{
"id":"12",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes B",
"quantity":"1",
"date":"2015-03-01",
"cost":"1500"
},
{
"total_qty":"2"
"total_cost":"4500"
}]
```

So, If I use this method, is it easier to append it as a row below the product items? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to declare variables for quantity and for total before foreach loop and then add values to it. Finally append a new tr after the each loop with values.

Your code would look like this:

```
var qty = 0,
  total = 0;

data.forEach(function(row) {
  var productname = row.uproducts_product;
  var productico = productname.replace(/\s+/g, "-") + '.png';
  var productcost = row.uproducts_total_investment;
  var str = '<tr>';
  str += '<td>' + '<img class="product_icon" src="images/products/icon-' + productico + '">' + '<div class="productname">' + row.uproducts_product + '</div></td>';
  str += '<td><div class="textinfo ">' + row.date + '<br/><span class="date">' + row.uproducts_date + '</span></div> </td>';
  str += '<td><span class="textinfo">' + row.uproducts_quantity + '</span></td>';
  str += '<td><span class="textinfo">' + productcost + '</td>';
  str += '</tr>';
  if (!isNaN(row.uproducts_quantity))
    qty += parseFloat(row.uproducts_quantity);
  if (!isNaN(productcost))
    total += parseFloat(productcost);

  $('#tbl-product').append(str);
});
$('#tbl-product').append('<tr><td colspan="2">Total</td><td>' + qty + '</td><td>' + total.toFixed(2) + '</td></tr>');
```

#### Explanation:

- `var qty = 0, total = 0;` Declare variables and set it's value to
  `0`. [More details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp).
- `if (!isNaN(row.uproducts_quantity))` will check whether
  `row.uproducts_quantity` value is a number or not. [More
  details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp).
- `parseFloat(row.uproducts_quantity)` will convert the string to
  integer. [More
  details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp).
- `qty += parseFloat(row.uproducts_quantity);` will add the value to
  `qty` variable in each loop.
- `total.toFixed(2)` will convert the number into a string, keeping
  only two decimals. [More
  Details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

---

### Updated as per OP question updates

First of all your json data is not in correct format. Second one you can use jquery `$.each`[jquery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through the json object. Refer [jquery loop on Json data using $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each) and [jQuery looping .each() JSON key/value not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969751/jquery-looping-each-json-key-value-not-working)

```js
var data = [{
"id":"11",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes A",
"quantity":"1",
"open":"2015-01-04",
"date":"2015-01-04",
"cost":"3000"
},

{
"id":"12",
"user_id":"8000",
"product":"Shoes B",
"quantity":"1",
"open":"2015-01-04",
"date":"2015-03-01",
"cost":"1500"
}];

$(function(){
  var qty = 0,
  total = 0;

$.each(data, function(i, row) {
  var productname = row.product;
  var productico = productname.replace(/\s+/g, "-") + '.png';
  var productcost = row.cost;
  var str = '<tr>';
  str += '<td>' + '<img class="product_icon" src="images/products/icon-' + productico + '">' + '<div class="productname">' + productname + '</div></td>';
  str += '<td><div class="textinfo ">' + row.date + '<br/><span class="date">' + row.open + '</span></div> </td>';
  str += '<td><span class="textinfo">' + row.quantity + '</span></td>';
  str += '<td><span class="textinfo">' + productcost + '</td>';
  str += '</tr>';
  if (!isNaN(row.quantity))
    qty += parseFloat(row.quantity);
  if (!isNaN(productcost))
    total += parseFloat(productcost);

  $('#tbl-product').append(str);
});
$('#tbl-product').append('<tr><td colspan="2">Total</td><td>' + qty + '</td><td>' + total.toFixed(2) + '</td></tr>');
  
});
```

```css
table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table th, table td {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl-product">
   <tr>
         <th>product</th>
         <th>date</th>
         <th>quantity</th>
         <th>cost</th>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

[jsfiddle output](https://jsfiddle.net/7tozb555/).

Just compare the json object with the example object I have created here. And you can use the server sided sum amount if you use `for (i=0; i > (obj.length-1); i++)` loop and finally get the last object key and value for total row.

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer. I tried to run your code but the append of row doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer was so clear, I was able to follow it easily. Thank you for the sample code, references and to your time.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Happy coding.

Comment: Just a quick question. How I can display this (`parseFloat(row.total_profit).toFixed(2)`) with a comma when the number is thousands. Example 1000.00 to 1,000.00? i have tried this short method `parseFloat(row.total_profit).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()` but nothing change.

Comment: @c.k http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753483/javascript-thousand-separator-string-format may be helpfull to you. please check it out.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to show summary automatically. You need create other variable in server side and then compute value from list objects to this variable. Bind summary variable to html as a normal row.

Comment: Who said it's not possible to sum up the values in foreach loop, in javascript, if you get values? See my answer above.